# Solidity - Running out of Gas during ERC Transfer method

Tags: solidity

I'm creating a game contract where the user will receive an ERC20 token if they win a bet.

At the end of the function I settle the bet and transfer the token.

When testing the app the transaction are failing 50% of the time when a user 'wins' and I need to transfer the token. This is my code.

```
if (won) {
            payout = (_amount * payoutMult);
            IERC20(TOKEN).transfer(address(msg.sender), payout);
}
```

Is there a way to make sure the user 'always' sends enough gas to make sure the transaction executes every time?

thank you

Comment: do you want to increase the gas amount on metamask when you send the transaction?

Comment: I'm sure that would solve the issue. I want to make sure the user doesn't have to do that automatically and that the total gas (including potential transfer) is taken into account.

Comment: you either has to specify while you send the transaction on the code or let metamask calculate the gas and then increase that amount manually on metamask